# Jquery .html and acentuation

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

First, i'm sorry for my english.

All right, i'm new at this jquery stuff. I'm doig a enable/disable button that uses `$.post();`

So:

```
$.post(goURL, {data: foo}).done(function(data){
     $('.error').html(data.type, data.message);
});
```

And in my php script i have:

```
<?php
     function enableThis()
     {
          $act = updateDatabase();
          if($act)
          {
               $data['type'] = 'success';
               $data['message'] = 'á é í ó ú';
          }else
          {
               $data['type'] = 'error';
               $data['message'] = 'á é í ó ú';
          }
          json_encode($data);
          exit;
     }
```

And that's it, the type is always all right, but the message returns like undefined.
After i put this:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The message returns the chars with acentuation with a (not this, just example) /156a8. But doest not fill the .error div with the message.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to parse the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `html()` only accepts one argument, using the comma you're sending it two arguments

```
$('.error').html(data.type + ', ' + data.message);
```

When you add a second argument, it's not outputted -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bFwM6/1/)

Comment: ah, i forgot, i created a function that handle the type and .html() right, i'm sorry